# Split input of itertools.product fairly before making the product

Tags: python, split, python-itertools

TL;DR: below

I have multiple lists of parameters which I must take all products of and run it in a function:

```
import numpy as np
import itertools

#Actual list elements are unimportant. Lists are different sized. 
listA = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
listB = [ 0.1, 0.2, 0.3 ]
listC = range(23)
# ... There are actually 7 lists but some are len(1) so I'll omit them here. 
listG = [ 5, 1 ]

def theFunction(paramA, paramB, paramC, paramG):
   print(f"{paramA} {paramB} {paramC} {paramG}")

for pA, pB, pC, pG in itertools.product(listA, listB, listC, listG):
   theFunction(pA, pB, pC, pG)
```

Now the number of products

```
numProducts = len(listA) * len(listB) * len(listC) * len(ListG)
```

grows quickly but I must split the whole thing into chunks (jobs) of similar runtime to be processed. I know how long each function takes, so the necessary numSplits is:

```
jobRuntime, functionRuntime = 36000, 1
numSplits = max(1, np.ceil(functionRuntime * numProducts / jobRuntime))
```

The whole product is too long to make the iterator into a list and use np.array_split(), and for each job to iterate over the whole thing is wasteful in computing resources (there is some filterfalse applied making it not so quick). The split method must also be deterministic since I do the split on the fly in each job. The job should also not be too quick, since there is some setup-time, which then is again wasteful in computing resources.

As long as numSplits <= longest list, I take np.array_split on the longest list: no problem (up to factor 2 runtime difference due to uneven split in e.g. numSplits=24 => listC becomes [0], [1], ..., [21,22] is okay.).

When numSplits > longestListSize and numSplits < longestListSize & 2ndlongestListSize, it starts getting a bit tricky. I came up with:

```
def getJobSplit2D(numSplits, dimSize1stLargest): 
    numJobs1stMostDim = int(dimSize1stLargest)
    while numSplits / numSplits1stMostDim % 1 != 0 and numSplits1stMostDim > 0:
        print(f"{numSplits} {numSplits1stMostDim} {numSplits / numSplits1stMostDim:.4g}")
        numSplits1stMostDim -= 1
    numJobs2ndMostDim = numSplits // numSplits1stMostDim
```

which has some checks afterwards, and when I fudge numSplits( 10% wiggle room is okay) a bit I find some suitable split quite fast. I.e. numSplits must not be prime etc., should not be e.g. 143 = 67*2 for the largest list size 65 etc. However, this clearly is not great. Also this can sort of lead to large runtime differences for each jobs since +-1 differences in two lists are now a factor of >= 4 differences in runtime.
Further, this approach get's terrible if I need a split in three or more dimensions.

Anyhow, all of this already took me longer than I want to admit, and I feel there must be a much more easy and clever way to do it which I just don't see.

I too thought about sorting the length of the lists in decreasing order and get the integer factors of numSplit with SymPy, which I can also sort:

```
from sympy.ntheory import factorint
lenList = [ 23, 5, 3, 2 ] #Values from example
factDict = factorint( 105 )  # -->{3: 1, 5: 1, 7: 1}
factList = [] 
for i, (k, v) in enumerate(factDict.items()):
    factList.extend([ k for _ in range(v)])
factList.sort(reverse=True) #-> [7,5,3]
```

And then divide the largest list using the factors as long as > 1. But this is not optimal for something like e.g. [ 24, 7, 3, 2] with [ 7, 6, 2, 2 ] which would be great for 6*2*2 = 24 and 7 = 7... (Or greatest common divisors, but then I find examples where the list sizes are prime and it is not really necessary that the lists are split without rest ...)

**TL;DR:** 
Instead of one itertools.product of some lists, I must split the lists to get numSplits products, where numSplits is some number I got in advance (with some 10% wiggle room to make it *suitable)*. Each of those split products should be *more or less* equal sized.

How do I find a deterministic split, so that given each list length, the number of splits to do and some jobID, and I process all jobs from jobID = 0 ... to numSplits-1, I compute every itertools.product of the full lists?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the iterating approach was not so dumb after all. It at least tries to split the lists into size-1. A general N-d approach:

```py
def getJobSplitAnyD(numJobs, dimSizes):
    dimSizesCopy = dimSizes.copy()
    dimSizes = np.array(dimSizes)
    numJobsDimN = np.full(len(dimSizes), 1, dtype=int)

    for i, ds in enumerate(dimSizes): #First see if perfect fit
        if numJobs == ds:
            numJobsDimN[i] = numJobs
            return True, numJobsDimN

    sortIdx = np.argsort(np.array(dimSizes), kind='stable')
    unSortIdx = np.argsort(sortIdx, kind='stable')
    
    dimSizes = dimSizes[sortIdx[::-1]]

    assert np.all(np.diff(dimSizes) <= 0), "dimSizes must be decreasing (starting from largest)"

    _numJobs = numJobs
    for idim, ds in enumerate(dimSizes):
        numJobsDimN[idim] = ds                         #Split first dimension completly
          #               Remainder is integer    and  this dimension is not split
        while _numJobs / numJobsDimN[idim] % 1 != 0 and numJobsDimN[idim] > 0:
            numJobsDimN[idim] -= 1                     #try smaller split

        _numJobs /= numJobsDimN[idim]                  #get remaining number of splits
        if _numJobs == 1:                              #all splits done, great work!
            break

    if _numJobs != 1:
        print(f"Could not find split - bad input number? Found so far: {numJobs} {numJobsDimN}")     #No error here - number was bad, is okay
        return False, []

    print("Split found:")
    for ds, nd in zip(dimSizes, numJobsDimN):
        print(f"{ds:<4} {nd:4}")
        
    #Undo sorting
    numJobsDimN = numJobsDimN[::-1][unSortIdx]
    dimSizes = dimSizes[::-1][unSortIdx]

    #Compare against copy that everything went correctly
    print("#copy undo num")
    for dsc, ds, nd in zip(dimSizesCopy, dimSizes, numJobsDimN):
        print(f"{dsc:<4} {ds:<4} {nd:4}")

    #Some checks
    for i, nd in enumerate(numJobsDimN):
        assert dimSizesCopy[i] >= nd, f"Error splitting {numJobs} of dimSizes {dimSizes}: {numJobsDimN} | Failure in dim: {i} and split {nd} of {dimSizes[i]}"
    assert np.product(numJobsDimN) == numJobs

    return True, numJobsDimN


### Some tests:
ll = [125, 2, 749, 34, 74]
print(getJobSplitAnyD(100, ll))
print(getJobSplitAnyD(124, ll))
print(getJobSplitAnyD(125, ll))
print(getJobSplitAnyD(201, ll))
print(getJobSplitAnyD(10000, ll))
print(getJobSplitAnyD(223439568, ll))
```

Overall larger to smaller ordering produces less splits and in particular less uneven splits.

One of the debug-prints is.

```
Split found:
749   625
125    16
74      1
34      1
2       1
#copy undo num
125  125    16
2    2       1
749  749   625
34   34      1
74   74      1
```

So seems to be working okay. Still interested if there are better solutions to find splits without rest.